# Google App Engine Standard can not find/execute Gunicorn

Tags: django, google-app-engine, gunicorn, google-cloud-build

I have a project with a Django backend and an Angular frontend. I've deployed them as two services into **Google App Engine Standard** and the deploy is **successful**.

However, when I try to access the backend url `this-backend.appspot.com`, i get

```
/bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found
```

I have **gunicorn** in my requirements file:

```
gunicorn==19.9.0
```

I also have defined the entrypoint:

```
runtime: python37
service: default

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT thisapp.wsgi

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

But still get the same error.

I looked into all the same issues on the Stackoverflow, and they were either because of the requirements or the entrypoint which I've defined both of them.

Even when I go to the **Stackdriver** I can see the gunicorn folders inside the `app engine:/`:

```
gunicorn
gunicorn-19.9.0.dist-info
```

This is the backend `cloudbuild.yaml` file:

```
steps:

  - name: 'python:3.7'                                                                                                                               
    entrypoint: python3                                                               
    args: ['-m', 'pip', 'install', '-t', '.', '-r', 'requirements.txt'] 

  - name: 'python:3.7'                                                            
    entrypoint: python3                                                           
    args: ['./manage.py', 'collectstatic', '--noinput']

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['app', 'deploy', '--version=prod']
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone has any solutions or recommendations as I've looked into almost all the same issues on the Internet.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App Engine by default looks for a `main.py` file at the root of the app directory with a WSGI-compatible object called app.

The doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#entrypoint_best_practices) suggests that you may include `gunicorn` in your `requirements.txt` file if you specify the entrypoint in your `app.yaml` file, however the version you want to install seems to conflict with the default one.

To work around this, I'd suggest you to remove both the gunicorn dependency in the requirements.txt file and the entrypoint in your app.yaml and create a main.py file like this:

```
from thisapp.wsgi import application

app = application
```

This way it'll fall back to the default behavior explained above and should work fine. It is also implemented this way in the official [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python37/django).

Comment: Very interesting! yeah i guess there was an issue with the versions. But I removed them and it worked.
Thank you so much!